# Unity3D Webplayer extension on pure Node.js server

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine

I can't run my Unity3D applications on my node.js server. It says "failed to download data file". I think it's because of MIME types. Here are my codes. I'm new to Javascript and Node.js, sorry for that.

Server.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');
var five = require("johnny-five"),board, led, button;

board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {
  button = new five.Button(2);
});

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world', function(err) { response.end(); });
            break;
        case '/index.html': 
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, function(err) { response.end(); });
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404", function(err) { response.end(); });
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(8001);

var ios = io.listen(server);
ios.listen(server);
ios.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    if (board.isReady) {
        button.on("down",function(){ 
            console.log("down");
            socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
        });
        socket.on('toggleLed', function(data){  
            led = new five.Led(13);
            led.strobe(1000);  
        });
        setInterval(function(){
            socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
        });
         socket.on('client_data', function(data){  
            process.stdout.write(data.letter);
        });
    }
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Unity Web Player | UnityArduino</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ssl-webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var unityObjectUrl = "http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js";
        if (document.location.protocol == 'https:')
            unityObjectUrl = unityObjectUrl.replace("http://", "https://ssl-");
        document.write('<script type="text\/javascript" src="' + unityObjectUrl + '"><\/script>');
        -->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            var config = {
                width: 960, 
                height: 600,
                params: { enableDebugging:"0" }

            };
            var u = new UnityObject2(config);

            jQuery(function() {

                var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");
                var $brokenScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".broken");
                $missingScreen.hide();
                $brokenScreen.hide();

                u.observeProgress(function (progress) {
                    switch(progress.pluginStatus) {
                        case "broken":
                            $brokenScreen.find("a").click(function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                u.installPlugin();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $brokenScreen.show();
                        break;
                        case "missing":
                            $missingScreen.find("a").click(function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                u.installPlugin();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $missingScreen.show();
                        break;
                        case "installed":
                            $missingScreen.remove();
                        break;
                        case "first":
                        break;
                    }
                });
                u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "ArduinoWebPlayer.unity3d");
            });
        -->
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        a:link, a:visited {
            color: #000;
        }
        a:active, a:hover {
            color: #666;
        }
        p.header {
            font-size: small;
        }
        p.header span {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        p.footer {
            font-size: x-small;
        }
        div.content {
            margin: auto;
            width: 960px;
        }
        div.broken,
        div.missing {
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            width: 193px;
        }
        div.broken a,
        div.missing a {
            height: 63px;
            position: relative;
            top: -31px;
        }
        div.broken img,
        div.missing img {
            border-width: 0px;
        }
        div.broken {
            display: none;
        }
        div#unityPlayer {
            cursor: default;
            height: 600px;
            width: 960px;
        }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="header"><span>Unity Web Player | </span>UnityArduino</p>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="unityPlayer">
                <div class="missing">
                    <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="broken">
                    <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install.">
                        <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now! Restart your browser after install." src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunityrestart.png" width="193" height="63" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="footer">&laquo; created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/unity/" title="Go to unity3d.com">Unity</a> &raquo;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is because of this server code.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world', function(err) { response.end(); });
            break;
        case '/index.html': 
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, function(err) { response.end(); });
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404", function(err) { response.end(); });
            break;
    }
});
```

I followed this code and found the solution.

https://github.com/jwanga/node-static-http-server